# MPAndroidChart chart padding

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I can't seem to enable padding on the horizontal `BarChart` in [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)... Like on the screenshot below..the word commentary is cut off..even on tablets, both orientations e.t.c
[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Have a look at the [viewport documentation](https://weeklycoding.com/mpandroidchart-documentation/modifying-the-viewport/) of the MPAndroidChart library.

There you find a method called `setExtraOffsets(float left, float top, float right, float bottom)` that allows to set additional offsets (as you require) for the chart.

Comment: I think this is a hack, not a solution! The library should calculate offsets based on the labels width/height!

Comment: It actually does, but only to some extent. If the labels are very long, the will be "chopped"

Answer (score 3):

`chart.minOffset = 0f`
it will remove space on `top/right/bottom/left`, but it have 1 problem. A half of the HIGHEST label on left/right axis will above (overflow) another view on top)

`chart.setViewPortOffsets(left, top, right, bottom)`
it help us set the space in `top/right/bottom/left` but from the axis not from the label (eg: if we set left = 0 we will not see the label on the left). so if I only want to set the space on top only, this function is not suitable

```
chart.setExtraOffsets(left, top, right, bottom)
chart.extraTopOffset
chart.extraBottomOffset
chart.extraRightOffset
```

it helps us set space to top/right/bottom/left but it is the **EXTRA** space so to make it look as same as the design (eg: 40dp), I use

```
chart.extraTopOffset = getDimension(R.dimen_40dp) - chart.minOffset
```

Answer (score 0):

Set this function in the `getFormattedValue` (if you use this) or in any suitable area.

```
bar.zoomOut()
```